# Replace a string with reactive form element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I get string content from a 3rd party API; the content is created using a Wysiwyg so it can have any number of html tags within it.  I need to replace some strings with select lists.

So, I might have a string like this:

```
<p>There are [howmany] dropdowns in this question</p>
```

Within the angular app, I want the final result to be:

```html
<p>There are 
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select> dropdowns in this question
</p>
```

I have all the replacement logic worked out, what I'm struggling with is maintaining the layout from the Wysiwyg **and** having a working form.

## Attempt 1

My idea was to use a pipe:

**component.ts**

```js
multipleDropDownForm: FormGroup;
...
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.generateForm();
  this.formString = new DropdownsPipe().transform(this.formStringParts, this.replacementVariables, this.multipleDropDownForm);
}

generateForm(): void {
  const group: any = {};
  this.replacementVariables.forEach(item => {
    group[item.asString] = new FormControl(item.asString, Validators.required);
  });

  this.multipleDropDownForm = new FormGroup(group);
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<div class="question__lead-in" [innerHTML]="formString">
  </div>
```

**dropdowns.pipe.ts**

```js
export class DropdownsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string[], replacementVars: ReplacementVariable[], form: FormGroup): any {
    let compiledString = `<div [formGroup]=${form}>`;
    value.forEach(v => {
      if (replacementVars.find(r => r.withBrackets === v) === undefined) {
        compiledString += v;
      } else {
        const rv = replacementVars.find(rvf => rvf.withBrackets === v);
        let select = `<select name="${rv.asString}" formControlName="${rv.asString}">`;
        rv.answerOptions.forEach(ao => {
          select += `<option value="${ao.id}">${ao.text}</option>`;
        });
        select += '</select>';

        compiledString += select;
      }
    });
    compiledString += '</div>';
    return compiledString ;
  }
}
```

From a presentation only point of view, this works great - I get the exact HTMl that is provided by the wysiwyg.  Functionally, it doesn't work.  Submitting the form simply shows the default controls as value:

[image]

The html output for this method is:
[image]

I'm only guessing that doing it this way doesn't allow Angular to properly register the `select` elements as form controls.

## Attempt 2

Use components

**select-list.component.html**

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  <select name="{{ replacement.asString }}" formControlName="{{ replacement.asString }}">
    <option *ngFor="let option of replacement.answerOptions" value="{{ option.id }}">{{ option.text }}</option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

**component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of formStringParts">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isReplacementVariable(s); else textLabelBlock">
      <app-select-list [form]="multipleDropDownForm" [replacement]="getReplacementVariable(s)"></app-select-list>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #textLabelBlock><span [innerHTML]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(s)"></span></ng-template>
  </ng-container>
```

Functionally, this works great.  It fails on presentation though because I end up with something like this as the HTML:

[image]

And this as the display (minor difference here, but could be more pronounced with more complicated HTML).  The image also shows that the correct values are available on submit.

[image]

The HTML output for this method is:
[image]

Is there a way to replace (n) strings with respective select lists that allows me to maintain the HTML from the API and work with submitting the form?

Comment: Cam you check the DOM and tell if "name" is set on the tag there or not?

Comment: @skyBlue in the first attempt (the pipe)?

Comment: I added screenshots of the generated HTML - "name" is set but there are clearly differences between the pipe method and component

Answer (score 1):

The first approach wont work because you are creating the html as a text in the pipe and angular will not be able to control this. It is just added as string during run time and browsers take care of rendering the html text you returned from pipe. So it is expected the form value is same as initial value.

The second approach seems fine. As the issue is only with the layouting or presentation, did you try making the app-select component and others in the html template as inline styled and giving appropriate line heights. Cannot say more than this without a reproduction.

Comment: Yes, I attempted to make the css inline but that's isn't maintainable when I could get any number of tags from a wysiwyg

Comment: You mean when the text is long and has many tags? What is the issue with maintainability with many tags?

Answer (score 0):

First I think if you don't need reactive forms features like validation, you can stop using reactive forms and you can use plain HTML forms it will be easy to implement.

If you really need reactive forms features and will proceed in the same approach, you can user ng-template tag, ngTemplateOutlet and ngTemplateContext attributes.

Comment: By plain html forms do you mean template driven?  I ask because I've tried using template driven but I get the same results.  The only validation needed is that every select list is required.

Comment: Yes Template driven forms it will be more easier. 
for the current approach I don't know how you submit the form
and I don't see "(ngSubmit)" in your code so if you are useing custom function to submit 
i think you need to handle onchange event of the dropdown and update attribute in your component like 
```
(change)="changeClassesLevel($event.target.value)" 
```

Comment: Sorry @mshehata, I didn't include that part of the code.  There is an `ngSubmit`; I did note that submitting the form in Attempt 2 does show the expected values in the console.  Right now my submit function just logs to console.